# How to add script with src and content in grails gsp?

Tags: javascript, grails, tradingview-api

I want to add javascript widget (https://www.tradingview.com/widget/market-overview/) in my gsp page. Not sure if latest version of grails stopped including javascript file with src tag from gsp file using . 
In my case I need to include the following script

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<span id="tradingview-copyright"><a ref="nofollow noopener" target="_blank" href="http://www.tradingview.com" style="color: rgb(173, 174, 176); font-family: &quot;Trebuchet MS&quot;, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">Market Quotes by <span style="color: #3BB3E4">TradingView</span></a></span>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-market-overview.js">
{
  "showChart": true,
  "locale": "en",
  "width": "400",
  "height": "400",
  "plotLineColorGrowing": "rgba(60, 188, 152, 1)",
  "plotLineColorFalling": "rgba(255, 74, 104, 1)",
  "gridLineColor": "rgba(233, 233, 234, 1)",
  "scaleFontColor": "rgba(218, 221, 224, 1)",
  "belowLineFillColorGrowing": "rgba(60, 188, 152, 0.05)",
  "belowLineFillColorFalling": "rgba(255, 74, 104, 0.05)",
  "symbolActiveColor": "rgba(242, 250, 254, 1)",
  "tabs": [
    {
      "title": "Equities",
      "symbols": [
        {
          "s": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
          "d": "Apple"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
</script>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

I have created a new gsp page with this content only but the chart is not showing. If I paste it in any html page (jsfiddle or w3schools), it works. Need help here.

Comment: Not showing why? Is there a JavaScript error in the browser console?

Comment: no js error in console. It seems like if I add any javascript file using src attribute of script tag in gsp pages, the file is not loaded!

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if there might be an issue with your particular Widget or maybe the constructor object you're passing it..

I was able to include this line in my GSP and it worked perfectly:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.openhub.net/p/grails/widgets/project_users?format=js&style=green'></script>
```

Perhaps you could try some other widgets from the same site? Or take a second look at your constructor object?